# What's the maximum voltage I can apply to this optoisolator?

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-electronics, opto-isolator

I have this circuit... The datasheet says there is voltage isolation up to 5000VRMS. I am trying to figure out maximum continuous operating voltage that can be applied to the diode side, pins SA, SB, and SC. I believe the datasheet says the maximum forward current for the diode is 50mA. The voltage being applied is a 3 phase voltage coming from a transformer secondary. How can I go about finding the maximum continuous voltage for pins SA, SB, and SC?

[image: optoisolator circuit]

Answer (score 1):

R50, R51 and R52 are 1 kΩ. The maximum opto-LED current is usually about 20 mA. That implies a maximum of 40 V or so phase to phase. You may be able to double it as the diodes are only conducting on one half-cycle.

The 5000 V<sub>RMS</sub> isolation usually refers to isolation between the LED and the photo-transistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6EkHm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) The equivalent circuit. (b) The circuit when 'A' is positive and 'B' is negative.*

You can see from Figure 1b that R1 and R2 total to 2 kΩ. At 20 mA this will drop 40 V.

D1 will only conduct when 'A' is positive with respect to either of the other two phases.

Comment: The datasheet https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/239/LTV-8x6-1175385.pdf ... appears to show a maximum forward current of 50mA. I'm curious how you calculated 40V? Also, are you saying that D38, D39, and D40 are attributing to the conduction of one half cycle? Or do you mean the diode in the chip?

Comment: See the update. If you can tolerate higher current then you can increase the voltage. Don't forget to factor in the peak rather than the RMS if that's relevant.

Comment: That was very thorough and extremely helplful! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Also be aware that the 1206 resistors have a maximum voltage rating; if you wanted to increase these to 10k so you could operate from a 230 or 400V supply then you may need to use multiple resistors in series.